# Group products and simplify PHP & MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Query:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
    <th>Provider</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="TablaVarios">
    <?php
    $results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE provider IN %ls", array('provider1', 'provider2', 'provider3'));

    foreach ($results as $row) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Ref'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Provider'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:

[image]

Basically what I am looking for is to obtain the prices grouped by reference code, since for each product I have a list of several prices of suppliers and the table is very large

[image]

Comment: N.B.: "providerX" and "PROVIDERx" are two different animals, given if that's your real code and looking for those exact values as posted.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner If I understand the difference and the code as well as this it works in a test table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `join` providers `2 and 3`. then use `sum()` function

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT Ref, sum(case when provider='provider1' then price else 0 end) as provider1
, sum(case when provider='provider2' then price else 0 end) as provider2
, sum(case when provider='provider3' then price else 0 end) as provider3
from providers   
where provider in ('provider1', 'provider2', 'provider3')
group by Ref");
```

Comment: It doesn't work, even changing "group by t1.ref" after %ls (I thought that was the error).

Comment: @altoca, try again

Comment: It doesn't work, I think the error must be in "ref" since my code uses "Ref" or I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @altoca, i moved the array inside the query, it should work the same, try again

Comment: ERROR: Column 'price' in field list is ambiguous.

Comment: Remove capital letters to adapt my table to your code and it still does not work, here is an image of the structure of my table: https://imgur.com/a/u6C1RY2

Comment: try now, type on case statement

Comment: Something is missing! You almost made it! https://imgur.com/a/OCZyu1s

Comment: I already have it, but it is not showing the prices of the database, apparently they are adding.

Comment: @altoca, try again, added case statement for providers 2 and 3

Comment: Get exactly the same, the first price (provider 1) is correct, the next two (provider2 and provider3) are still added. What I have to get is: 1000001 / 100.00 / 99.00 / 101.00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202772/discussion-between--and-altoca).